# Make a python script API

Tags: python, api, nginx, centos7

I have a script on python, which prints some data. The script is on Centos7, nginx.

How could I connect to the script via URL (GET query) to be able to parse the data?

Comment: You will have to create a RESTful webservice (eg. with flask, there are many tutorials online just google for flask restful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a framework like Django or flask to make an api out of it. I'll suggest flask since it's very light-weight, making it ideal for such small tasks.

E.g.

```
def your_function(input):
    # do something
    return output


from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/my_api')
def your_api_function():
    input = request.args.get('my_query_string')
    return your_function(input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And then use the endpoint

> /my_api?my_query_string=my_input

You can further play around with it to return JSON, take parameters from request body and so on and so forth.

Read more here http://flask.pocoo.org/